# Powershell Script continues to ask me to use Select-AzureSubscription although I have called it

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I have an Azure runbook where I am trying to deallocate VMs. When I run the runbook I get the error

```
Stop-AzureVM : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to 
set the default subscription.
```

I have used the below in my script.

```
Add-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRMSubscription
```

After calling the select, it prints out

```
PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : 
Account               : 
Environment           : 
Subscription          : 
Tenant                :
```

with the correct subscrption and tenant information so it seems the select is working correctly, but for some reason I still cannot use the `Stop-AzureVM` cmdlet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the type of your Azure VM? Classic or  Resource Manager? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-modelshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models.

Comment: The link that you provided is broken. how would I tell if the VM is Resource Manager. I believe it is classic but not 100 percent sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `Stop-AzureVM` is Azure Service Management PowerShell command. It just can be used to stop Azure classic VM. But the command `Add-AzureRmAccount` is Azure Resource Management PowerShell command. After running the command, we just can manage Azure Resource Management resources. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/overview?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models).

So with Azure ARM VM, please use the command [`Stop-AzureRmVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/stop-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to stop it. Meanwhile, regarding how to stop Azure classic VM, please refer to the following steps

1. Create [Azure Classic Run As Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-security-overview#azure-classic-run-as-account)
2. Script

```
$ConnectionAssetName = "AzureClassicRunAsConnection"
# Get the connection
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
$CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
$AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

#stop VM
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName "ContosoService01" -Name "MyVM" -Force
```

Besides, regarding how to check if the VM is classic, please refer to the [blog](https://support.cloudmonix.com/support/solutions/articles/12000027792-how-do-i-verify-if-azure-resources-are-using-arm-or-classic-api-#:%7E:text=An%20easy%20way%20to%20check,is%20using%20the%20ARM%20API.)

Comment: Such a small error. Changed the cmdlet to Stop-AzureRmVM and got things working. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Running the below :

```
Get-Module AzureRm.Profile -ListAvailable
```

This issue might occur when there is multiple instances of the module.  If there are multiple instance remove the older modules and retain the new module.

To remove the old module : `Uninstall-Module -Name AzureRm.Profile   -RequiredVersion 4.6.0#(olderversion if you have any)`

Comment: Looks like I have only one instance of the module. It is not the newest version, but that was done on purpose. Any other ideas?